# partial derivative of $L^2$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the chapter on energy methods for partial differential equations I saw the following:
$$\frac{d\|u\|_2^2}{dt}=(u,u_t)+(u_t,u)=\cdots$$
So, why we can't just write $$\frac{d\|u\|_2^2}{dt}=2(u,u_t)=\cdots?$$

Are these two the same, or there is a reason I have to consider the derivative as in the first expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real valued functions, the two are indeed the same. For complex valued functions, the inner product is sesquilinear and Hermitian (not necessarily symmetric), so complex conjugation comes into play.